# My Madden Ultimate Team has no healthy REs

Tags: madden-12

Alright, I just started playing an Ultimate Team because I want the last few achievements for the game. Right now I have a bunch of 50-60 rated players from the starter pack and a few players from playing the demo before launch. My problem is that in my very first game my Right Defensive End got injured and I didn't get any other REs in my Starter Pack. During the game I was simply able to put a Defensive Tackle in his place and keep playing, but now that the game is over I get an error "Your RE position is empty. You must have a player active for every position before you can play a game."

If I go to the depth chart to the empty RE spot and put the same DT in the spot the game appears to "change" the position to DT instead of RE because of what the player's position is listed as before I put him in the spot. This results in the same error as above.

I don't have an injury card to use on him and I only have about 200ish coins from my first game so I can't afford to buy an injury card or a player to replace him.

1. Is there a way to fix this bug without having to spend real money to buy coins or player packs?
2. Is there a way to start a new Ultimate Team and keep my 3 bonus players and my coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting another RE (finally) and putting him in my lineup I still got the error. I started mashing buttons on my controller... and then I found out that pressing R3 (PS3 controller) on the player lineup screen with the picture cards opens up an actual depth chart list where your can move players around to different positions. Had I known this a week ago I wouldn't have needed to get another RE at all and could have just played my backup DT in his spot.

On the player lineup screen (Shows the player cards and their position) if you press R3 (on the PS3) or whatever the equivalent is on other systems, you will open a depth chart where you can move your players around.

Comment: Good to know ... I'd forgotten that the depth chart works the same way in UT that it does in the other modes.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, within the game this isn't a problem because you can play pretty much anyone at any position to replace an injured player. (Playing someone from a related position, like playing a DT or an OLB at DE, will work better than playing someone at an unrelated position. You'll see this in the depth chart when you look at ratings for that position: the ratings you see are the ratings for each player at the position you're seeing, not at their natural position.)

Also as you've seen, once the game is over, it's not as easy to fix. As you note in your answer, you can't move a non-RE to RE without going to the depth chart screen. (This is a good screen to remember - another common problem is having an injury or an expired contract that invalidates a spot on your kick or punt return team.)

If you don't want to spend real cash, then another option is to trade for a RE. This will probably require you to find someone with an extra RE who also doesn't need a lot in return ... but I think that's your best option. To my knowledge, there's no way to reset your Ultimate Team.

Here are some details on trading from [EA's blog](http://www.ea.com/madden-nfl/blog/madden-ultimate-team-12-details). Note that this was posted in June 2011, so trading may not work exactly as listed below.

> - Any card type can be traded. Players, coaches, stadiums, playbooks, legendary cards, etc.
> - 1-for-1 Trades – multiple card trades is something we are looking at for the future in Madden Ultimate Team, but in Madden NFL 12, we have 1-for-1 trades.
> - Post to Trade Block fee – there will be a fee associated with posting trades (only in the event that the trade is successfully completed).
> - You can trade with friends or make deals with complete strangers! Just like the Auction Block, you have the ability to search through trade offers from others or send a card to your own Trade Block.
> - You have the ability to set the overall rating range of the player you want in return for the trade. This ensures that you will not get spammed with junk trade offers.

I haven't traded before, so I don't know how much the fee is or when it applies.

There are quite a few places where you could look for trading partners, including [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and the Madden 12 forum on [xbox360achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=326868). As always, use caution when trading with someone whom you don't know, even if you are just trading a low-value card; don't share anything other than your gamertag, and definitely don't give your login information to anyone else, even if they're promising to get you a really great card.

Comment: Do you know if the Ultimate Team requires the online code to function with an EA account? Or can I create a new account on my PS3 and make a new Ultimate Team and trade with myself?

Comment: I don't know for sure. From what they've said about [Online Pass](http://www.easports.com/onlinepass), without a code, you can use offline functions, but not online functions, so I suspect you would not be able to make a trade with another account unless you bought another code. You can always ask in chat here or post in forums if you need a trade partner.

Comment: Just a note. You can actually start another Madden Ultimate Team on another profile with a new EA Sports account (But you do not need another Online Pass code). I needed a separate email for the new account because it checks if the email you enter is already signed up for an EA account, but I was able to make a new team. I cannot trade beginner player cards however so I am still stuck on my main account for a while until I can find someone to trade with.

Comment: I thought that might be a problem. I'll update my answer with links to places where you might be able to find a trading partner.